# If $c\ne-1,0,1,\,$ then is it true that $(x=3\iff c^x=c^3)\;?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Is following statement true? $$\forall x{\in}\mathbb{R}\quad\forall c{\in}\mathbb{R}{\setminus}\{-1,0,1\}   \quad(x=3\iff c^x=c^3).$$

Or to really get across what I am trying to ask I will formulate it in German:

Wenn ich die Gleichung $(x=3)$ habe und diese zu $(c^x=c^3)$ umforme, war das eine Äquivalenzumformung unter der Voraussetzung dass Fälle $c=-1$, $c=0$ und $c=1$ ausgeschlossen werden?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138285/discussion-on-question-by-tempdev-nova-if-c-ne-1-0-1-then-is-it-true-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to the comment/question of tempdev nova.

---

No, the statement is not true.

What is true is that $(x = 3) \rightarrow c^x = c^3.$

The issue that you are indirectly focusing on is the following.  When you start with a specific set of premises, perform algebraic manipulations on these premises, and then  arrive at a set of values that satisfy the manipulated equations, what is the relationship between the determined set of values and the original premise(s)?

In general, what you will have established is that **if** a specific value (for example) for $(x)$ satisfies the original premise(s), then it must be an element in the set that satisfies the manipulated equations.

This implies that it is impossible for any **other** value of $(x)$ to satisfy the premise(s), other than the set of values that you have derived.  This is **totally distinct** from saying that every element in the derived set will automatically satisfy the original premise(s).

Instead, the derived set represents **candidate values**, each of which must be manually examined against the original premises, to see whether the specific value satisfies the original premises.

---

Focusing on the specific problem that you raised, suppose that $c \in \{0,1\}.$  Then, you could well have $c^x = c^3$, without $x = 3.$  However, as indicated at the start of my answer, what you **can not** have is $x = 3$ without this implying that $c^x = c^3.$

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment/question of tempdev nova.

> If I exclude the cases where $c=0$ and $c=1$ would it work?

This is a complicated question.  For simplicity, I will narrow the question to the realm of Real Analysis, as opposed to Complex Analysis.

In Real Analysis, you generally avoid applying a non-integer exponent to a negative base.  For example,

$$[-1]^{(1/2)}, ~~\text{and}~~ [-1]^{\left(\sqrt{2} ~\right)} ~~\text{are both undefined}.$$

Therefore, in answer to your question, I will assume that $c$ is restricted by

$$c > 0 ~: c \neq 1. \tag1 $$

Through out the remainder of this answer, I will use the syntax $\log(r)$ to represent the natural logarithm of $(r)$, (i.e. base $e$).  In the pre-Calculus world, for all of the following analysis, you could substitute logarithms base $(10)$ for logarithms, base $(e)$.

Note that with $c$ constrained as in (1) above, that:

- $\log(c)~$ is well defined.
- $\log(c) \neq 0.$

In Real Analysis, the function $f(x) = e^x$ is a strictly increasing function, for all Real numbers $(x)$.  This implies that

$$e^{x_1} = e^{x_2} \leftrightarrow x_1 = x_2. \tag2 $$

Suppose that

$$e^{x\log(c)} = c^x = c^3 = e^{3\log(c)}.$$

By (2) above, this implies that

$$x\log(c) = 3\log(c). \tag3 $$

Since $c$ is constrained so that it has a non-zero logarithm, both sides of the equation in (3) above may be divided by $\log(c).$

Therefore, you can conclude that

$$x = 3.$$

Comment: If I exclude the cases where c=0 and c=1 would it work?

Comment: @tempdevnova See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty I have is that if $c < 0$ then $c^x$ is not universally agreed upon in meaning.

If $c > 0; c\ne 1$ then the function $f: \mathbb R \to (0, \infty)$ via $x \to c^x$ is injective and invertible.  That is why logarithms are well defined functions[1].  (As $c^x= M$ has only one solution defining $\log_c M$ as "the $x$ so that $c^x =M$" is legitimate and $\log_c M = x \iff c^x = M$).  In that case $c^x = c^3 \iff \log_c c^x = \log_c c^3 \iff x = 3$ is indeed true.

If $c < 0$ then $c^x$ is not defined if $x$ is rational and in its lowest terms has an even denominator nor is it defined if $x$ is irrational.  However if $x=3$ then $c^3 = c\times c \times c$ is defined and if $x = 3$ then anything we do with $x$ will be the same as doing it to $3$ so $c^x = c^3$ by definition.  And if $c^x$ is defined (which is only the case if $x$ is rational and has an odd denominator in its lowest terms) and if $c \ne -1$ then $c^x = -|c|^x$ and $-|c|^x = -|c|^3 = c^3$ only if $|c|^x = |c|^3$ and that is only true if $x = \log_{|c|}|c|^x = \log_{|c|}|c|^3 = 3$.

So yes.   If $c \ne -1, 0 , 1$ then $c^x = c^3 \iff x =3$.

=====

[1] It is *VERY* important to realize that logarithms with base $0$ or negative or with base $1$ are not well defined.  There is no such thing as $\log_1 M$. But if $c \ne 1$ and $c > 0$ then $\log_c M$ as the unique solution to $c^x = M$ is very well defined.